Path planning in Moveit2 using 2 planners
in my launch file, I am launching a hybrid planning container that is similar in the one in the hybrid planning tutorial, here is how i am launching it:
hybrid_planning_container = ComposableNodeContainer(
        name="hybrid_planning_container",
        namespace="/",
        package="rclcpp_components",
        executable="component_container",
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            ComposableNode(
                package="moveit_hybrid_planning",
                plugin="moveit::hybrid_planning::GlobalPlannerComponent",
                name="global_planner",
                parameters=[
                    common_hybrid_planning_param,
                    global_planner_param,
                    robot_description,
                    robot_description_semantic,
                    kinematics_yaml,
                    planning_pipelines_config,  
                    moveit_controllers,
                ]
            ),
            ComposableNode(
                package="moveit_hybrid_planning",
                plugin="moveit::hybrid_planning::LocalPlannerComponent",
                name="local_planner",
                parameters=[
                    common_hybrid_planning_param,
                    local_planner_param, 
                    robot_description,
                    robot_description_semantic,
                    kinematics_yaml,
                ],
            ),
            ComposableNode(
                package="moveit_hybrid_planning",
                plugin="moveit::hybrid_planning::HybridPlanningManager",
                name="hybrid_planning_manager",
                parameters=[
                    common_hybrid_planning_param,
                    hybrid_planning_manager_param],
            ),
           
        ],
        output='screen',
    )

All these parameters are initialized before and should be working properly. when I launch the file, I get an error that the global planner is not working. The local planner and the hybrid planner nodes are correctly initialized and loaded. I extracted the error part from the terminal and here it is:
[component_container-3] [WARN] [1731589975.248067920] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[component_container-3] [ERROR] [1731589975.248097734] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[component_container-3] [INFO] [1731589985.285746488] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 10.000000 seconds. Requested time 1731589975.285665, but latest received state has time 7.917000.
[component_container-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[component_container-3] [FATAL] [1731589985.285855453] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Unable to configure planning scene monitor
[component_container-3] [INFO] [1731589985.286258651] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopped publishing maintained planning scene.
[component_container-3] [INFO] [1731589985.286312558] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopping world geometry monitor
[component_container-3] [INFO] [1731589985.286344177] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Stopping planning scene monitor
[component_container-3] [ERROR] [1731589985.316760111] [hybrid_planning_container]: Component constructor threw an exception: Unable to configure planning scene monitor
[ERROR] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Failed to load node 'global_planner' of type 'moveit::hybrid_planning::GlobalPlannerComponent' in container '/hybrid_planning_container': Component constructor threw an exception: Unable to configure planning scene monitor

I am not running ROS on any other machine; I am only running this launch file on one PC and it is not connected to something else.
Here are the configuration files that I have for the global and local planner:
Global Planner:
global_planner_name: "moveit_hybrid_planning/MoveItPlanningPipeline"
global_planning_action_name: global_planning_action

# The rest of these parameters are typical for moveit_cpp
planning_scene_monitor_options:
  name: "planning_scene_monitor"
  robot_description: "robot_description"
  joint_state_topic: "/joint_states"
  attached_collision_object_topic: "/attached_colission_object"
  # Subscribe to this topic (The name comes from the perspective of moveit_cpp)
  publish_planning_scene_topic: "/planning_scene"
  # Publish this topic, e.g. to visualize with RViz
  monitored_planning_scene_topic: "/global_planner/planning_scene"
  wait_for_initial_state_timeout: 10.0
planning_pipelines:
  pipeline_names: ["ompl"]
plan_request_params:
  planning_attempts: 1
  planning_pipeline: ompl
  max_velocity_scaling_factor: 1.0
  max_acceleration_scaling_factor: 1.0

Local Planner:
robot_description: "robot_description"
trajectory_operator_plugin_name: "moveit_hybrid_planning/SimpleSampler"
local_constraint_solver_plugin_name: "moveit_hybrid_planning/ForwardTrajectory"
local_planning_frequency: 100.0
global_solution_topic: "global_trajectory"
local_solution_topic: "/local_planner/solution" #or panda_arm_controller/joint_trajectory
local_solution_topic_type: "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory" # or std_msgs/Float64MultiArray
publish_joint_positions: true
publish_joint_velocities: false
group_name: "ysio"
# Subscribe to this topic
monitored_planning_scene: "/planning_scene"
collision_object_topic: "/collision_object"
joint_states_topic: "/joint_states"

# ForwardTrajectory param
stop_before_collision: true

I am not sure if the 3D sensor error is related to the error after but i do not think so, but for reference i will attach here my sensors_3d.yaml file in case there is something that might be wrong with it. I have four cameras that are defined in the urdf file of the robot.
sensors:
 - camera_1
 - camera_2
 - camera_3
 - camera_4
camera_1:
  far_clipping_plane_distance: 5.0
  image_topic: /camera_1/camera/depth/image_raw
  point_cloud_topic: /camera_1/camera/depth/points
  max_update_rate: 1.0
  near_clipping_plane_distance: 0.3
  padding_offset: 0.03
  padding_scale: 4.0
  queue_size: 5
  sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
  shadow_threshold: 0.2
camera_2:
  far_clipping_plane_distance: 5.0
  image_topic: /camera_2/camera/depth/image_raw
  point_cloud_topic: /camera_2/camera/depth/points
  max_update_rate: 1.0
  near_clipping_plane_distance: 0.3
  padding_offset: 0.03
  padding_scale: 4.0
  queue_size: 5
  sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
  shadow_threshold: 0.2
camera_3:
  far_clipping_plane_distance: 5.0
  image_topic: /camera_3/camera/depth/image_raw
  point_cloud_topic: /camera_3/camera/depth/points
  max_update_rate: 1.0
  near_clipping_plane_distance: 0.3
  padding_offset: 0.03
  padding_scale: 4.0
  queue_size: 5
  sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
  shadow_threshold: 0.2
camera_4:
  far_clipping_plane_distance: 5.0
  image_topic: /camera_4/camera/depth/image_raw
  point_cloud_topic: /camera_4/camera/depth/points
  max_update_rate: 1.0
  near_clipping_plane_distance: 0.3
  padding_offset: 0.03
  padding_scale: 4.0
  queue_size: 5
  sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
  shadow_threshold: 0.2


Smells like some of your nodes are running with the real clock and some others are running with the simulated clock.
[component_container-3] [INFO] [1731589985.285746488] 
[moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 10.000000 seconds. Requested time 1731589975.285665, but latest received state has time 7.917000.
[component_container-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!

Be sure to make a consistent use of the use_sim_time parameter for all your nodes.

Yes I solved it a while ago, but i forgot to write it here, some of the nodes were running on the system clock and not the simulation clock. So, the time stamps of the joint states were messed up. It still causing another clock problem, but it actually solves this specific problem :) Thank you

Could you solve it? I believe this issue may be related to time synchronization problem, check:
[component_container-3] [INFO] [1731589985.285746488] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 10.000000 seconds. Requested time 1731589975.285665, but latest received state has time 7.917000.
[component_container-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
